# why the archive of custom taxonomy term shows nothing?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives, terms

I have a custom post type for which I have created a custom taxonomy called 'tag'. `taxonomy-tag.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>

      <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $term->name; ?> Archives</h1>

      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

          <div class="post type-post hentry">

              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
              </a>
          </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When this code is executed, it displays only things outside the loop. The loop find no result even if I have many posts of the specific custom post type bind to many terms of the custom taxonomy.

Have you faced such issue? I am stuck and your help is highly invaluable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure tag is a reserved keyword ($tag, $_GET['tag'] etc should not be used) in WordPress, as well as a taxonomy already defined by WordPress (for posts).

Comment: Yes @powerbuoy, and that was the problem. Thanks for your answer, if only it comes a few time before I could resolve the problem earlier. Thanks anyway, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

At the beginning I thought I resolved my problem after creating a new query with the arguments I need. The code I added is:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => 'post_type_name',
    'tax_query' => array(
                      array('taxonomy' => 'tag','terms' =>  $term->term_id)));

 $query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Then After Milo Remark, I discovered that I should never have to perform the default query myself in the template, the main query happens before the template is loaded. Then I was needing a way to inspect the `$wp_query` global to see why the main query is failing. The way to do so is to:

```
 echo '<pre dir="ltr">';
    print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
  echo '</pre>';
```

Result is:

```
[query_vars] => Array
        (
            [tag] => alaa
   ....................................
            [taxonomy] => tag
            [term] => alaa
```

As you can see here, I have 'alaa' as my term name and also as my post tag. It comes from the fact that I am defining a custom taxonomy with the name 'tag', which gives the same url for 2 different things. In other words, `blog/tag/alaa` will refer to archive of default posts with tag 'alaa' and will refer to archive of custom-post-type posts with custom taxonomy `'tag'` and term name `'alaa'`.

So I changed my custom taxonomy name while registering from `'tag'` to `'othername'`.

Now, Wordpress consider `blog/tag/alaa` and `blog/othername/alaa` as two different things, naturally.

Note that, my changes didn't take effect till I clicked on save changes under permalinks settings without making any change (maybe to refresh rewrite rules).

Comment: You should never have to perform the default query yourself in the template, the main query happens *before* the template is loaded. Inspect the $wp_query global to see why the main query is failing.

Comment: That is what I know, but I really wasted a lot of time to make the main query work but to no avail. I will give a feedback after trying to inspect wp_query

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I inscpect wp_query? I am a beginner and I dont find how.  I feel this technique is very useful. thanks in advance

Comment: I can now display $GLOBALS['wp_query'], but how can I know from this big array that my main query is failing? thank you for your time.

Comment: wrap the output in <pre> tags to make it more readable, compare the query vars and query being sent to the database with the custom query you perform above to see how they differ.

Comment: You are right, I see that maybe the fact that I have a taxonomy with name "tag" is causing a problem. Look please in my edit.

Comment: Yes, What was calling the problem is the fact of having a custom taxonomy with name "tag". When I changed it, I resolved my problem, but after clicking on save changes under my permalinks structure. Thank you Milo, I will provide with a complete solution to this issue as an edit.

Answer (score 2):

You solved this yourself by running a new query, but a new query should not be necessary as @Milo states in the comments to your question. The main query should be doing automatically what your secondary query is doing.

I suspect this has something to do with the way you have [registered that custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), since I am able to duplicate this problem only when I register a type with a `'public' => false` argument. There may be other arguments that could do this, or argument combinations, but that is the only one I found in my less than exhaustive search. Use `'public' => true` when you register the post type, if you are not already doing so.

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum but my post type is already registred with 'public' => true.

Comment: Dear S_ha_dum, I wrote  the solution that I found to my problem, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

For custom post types, you'll need to hook `pre_get_posts`. By default the taxonomy pages only show posts of type `post`, `page`, and `attachment`.

```
// Ensure that our custom post types appear in the taxonomy archive pages
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type_to_taxonomy');
function add_my_custom_post_type_to_taxonomy($query) {
  if (empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])) {
    if (is_tax('my_custom_taxonomy_type')) {
      $query->set('post_type', array('my_custom_post_type'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not necessary. Just register the post type and the taxonomy with proper arguments, and WordPress will show them automatically.

Comment: I may have done something wrong then, because my custom post type wasn't being displayed on my custom taxonomy archive page.

Comment: I just checked my code again and I'm still having an issue without my `pre_get_posts` action. What arguments am I missing? I used the custom post type and custom taxonomy generators on [GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/).